# How can I make an iterable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iterable

I'm trying to understand iterables in JavaScript by creating a range function, but it doesn't work

I'm trying to understand iterables in JavaScript so I created a range function that when I call it, it will return a range of numbers for me e.g:

```
for (let i of Range(5)) console.log(i);
0
1
2
3
4
```

here is the code for doing it.

```
// log function
const log = console.log;

// Range constructor 
function Range(end, start, step = 1) {
    if (!new.target) {
        return new Range(start, end, step);
    }
    end = start ? start : end;
    start = start ? end : 0;
    step = step;
    
    return {
        start,
        end,
        step,
        [Symbol.iterator]() {
            return this;
        },
        next() {
            if (this.start < this.end) {
                this.start += this.step;
                return {
                    done: false,
                    value: this.start - this.step
                };
            } else {
                return { done: true };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run it, return the numbers one after another e.g.

```
let range = new Range(6);
for (i of range) log(i);
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

but when I run it like `for (let i of Range(5) log(i);` it return `undefined` Why!

**update** if fixed the problem by updating `return new Range(start, end, step);` to `return new Range(end, start, step);` and `end = start ? start : end;` to `end = start ?? end;`

so when I run

```
let range = new Range(5); 
for (let i of range) log( i ); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
for (let i of Range(10) ) log( i ); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

but a new problem raised

```
let arr = Array.from(range); 
log(arr) // []
```

how to fix it

Comment: for (let i of Range(5) log(i); misses a ')'

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the harder `[Symbol.iterator]` approach instead of a `function*` ?

Comment: Fix the order of the arguments: `return new Range(end, start, step);`

Comment: `start ? start : ...` won't work with `start = 0`. Use `start ?? end` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up your arguments in `new Range(start, end, step)` (thanks @Unmitigated). It should be `new Range(end, start, step)`.

---

FYI a generator function is far simpler.

```js
function* range(start, end, step = 1) {
  if (end === undefined) {
    end = start;
    start = 0;
  }
  for (; start < end; start += step) {
    yield start;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, the code is not fine. The order of the arguments in `new Range(start, end, step)` is wrong.

Comment: @Unmitigated, ah

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ?

```
 let range = {
   from: 1,
   to: 5
 };

 // 1. call to for..of initially calls this. 
 range[Symbol.iterator] = function() {

  return {
      current: this.from,
      last: this.to,

      // 3. next() is called on each iteration by the for..of loop
     next() {
        if (this.current <= this.last) {
            return {
                done: false,
                value: this.current++
            };
        } else {
            return {
                done: true
            };
        }
     }
  };
};

for (let num of range) {
 console.log(num); // 1, then 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```

**UPDATE**

If we need to consider `stepSize` we can define a function as follows:

```
function myInterator(start = 0, end = 5, step = 1) {
 let nextIndex = start;
 let iterationCount = 0;

 const rangeIterator = {
   next() {
     let result;
     if (nextIndex < end) {
       result = { value: nextIndex, done: false };
       nextIndex += step;
       iterationCount++;
       return result;
      }
    return { value: iterationCount, done: true };
   },
};
 return rangeIterator;
}
```

Now, use the function as follows:

```
const it = myIterator(1, 5, 1);

 let result = it.next();
 while (!result.done) {
  console.log(result.value); // 1 2 3 4 5
  result = it.next();
 }
```

Comment: Your solution is good but I'm trying something more general can be used in different cases.